# Decision problem

Tags: reductions, undecidability, decision-problem, decidability

Prove the following theorem

- Let A and B be two languages on an alphabet Σ. If A ≤p B and B ∈ P, then A ∈ P.

Could anyone be able to prove it?

Comment: We discourage posts that are nothing more than the text of an exercise-style task.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard theorem. You can prove it using the definition of $\le_p$ which guarantees some *poly-time* function $f:\Sigma^*\rightarrow \Sigma^*$ with the property that $x\in A\iff f(x)\in B$.

Since $f$ is poly-time computable, then $f(x)$ can be computed. Then, since $B\in P$, we can again answer whether $f(x)\in B$ with polynomial time.

There is a small caveat though - computing whether $f(x)\in B$ is polynomial with respect to the size of $f(x)$, and not of $x$ as we would like. But since $f$ is polynomially computable, we can guarantee that $|f(x)|$ is polynomial in $|x|$, and thus, since polynomials are preserved under composition - we know that a polynomial in $|f(x)|$ is a polynomial in $|x|$, solving the problem. Finally - this means we can compute whether $f(x)\in B$ in polynomial time with respect to $|x|$, and thus also $x\in A$ is polynomially computable.